# Where are the SSL certificates issued by AWS are stored on the server so I can direct Neo4J to them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, neo4j, aws-certificate-manager

I issued an SSL certificate via AWS Certificate Manager. Now I need to point my Neo4J database to that certificate (this is by inner design of this graph database, which accesses the server via bolt).

Before, when I issued them using Let's Encrypt, I'd simply locate them on the server's harddrive and direct Neo4J to them as described in this article by Neo4j: https://medium.com/neo4j/getting-certificates-for-neo4j-with-letsencrypt-a8d05c415bbd

However, if I prefer to have a certificate issued by AWS, how do I locate them on my EC2 instance? Where are they located, so I direct Neo4J to them? Or are they not on the server at all? In this case, is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use certs provisioned by AWS ACM on the server because ACM manages the private key. You can either terminate SSL on the load balancer, or get one from a provider on your server. You can have a secure connection w/ SSL terminating on the ELB. I'm not sure about how to use it with Neo4j.

Terminating SSL on ALB

https://infra.engineer/aws/36-aws-ssl-offloading-with-an-application-load-balancer